# How to select element by "alt" value or "src" value

Tags: jscript

There is a web page , with image button which look like below  ...

```
<input alt="I am a unique value" type="image" src="https://abc/xyz/UniquePictureName.gif">
```

i need to able select it by either using "alt" value or "src" value then click , how can i write the code using DOM ?

I want use simple code like below but select using "alt" value or "src" value . I cant select this elements using css , id or name due to N\A

```
document.getElementsByID("XYZ").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector like this:

```
document.querySelector('[alt="I am a unique value"]').click();
```